# XSD elements - adding displayname for UI display

Tags: xml, xsd

So we have an XSD schema which we use to generate a UI, to create an XML document that conforms to the schema. For all the XElements in the schema, we want to have a display name to be used for the UI, rather than just the element name which is not very human readable.

Edit: we use C# and Linq to parse the XSD and generate the UI. There is no tool.

The original idea was to use annotations/appInfo to add custom 'comment type' attributes to every element, but it got extremely verbose, obfuscating the core purpose of the schema. So we were wondering whether we can just add a 'displayName' attribute to the XSD schema elements, that will not necessarily translate to the XML data requiring that attribute.

E.g. XSD before :-

```
<xs:element name="grnBulb" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <displayname>Bulbasaur</displayname>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

XSD after :-

```
<xs:element name="grnBulb" type="xs:string" displayname="Bulbasaur" />
```

in either case, the require XML data is the same :-

```
<grnBulb>Awesome</grnBulb>
```

and the displayname is only used for UI display (Bulbasaur : textbox). Is this possible / feasible, or are they better ways to accomplish the same task?

Comment: What tool are you using to convert your XSD schema into a UI view?

Comment: no tool - C# code and Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final degree project was a multiplatform mobile app that used XML Schema for the same purpose, in addition, if the user wants he/she could also use  XSLT to transform the XML document to HTML or PDF, and used Schematron to add semantic restrictions (assertions) that allowed me to implement error prevention. `DisplayName` is a great improvement for the app, so I also had this problem before and come to the solution you are talking about.

As [XML Schema Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) says in every element you can add

> {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>

and the XML Schema is still valid with those attributes. This is easier than use `xs:appinfo`, why not use it? So **you can create your own namespace for your improvements**. Note that you maybe want to add more improvements in the future.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:imp="http://myImprovementsURI.com">
    <xs:element name="grnBulb" type="xs:string" imp:displayname="Bulbasaur"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Since I implemented a similar functionality I will tell you some of the improvements that I added to the namespace just in case you want to know them:

- *imp:label* - this is the same as your *displayName* for both *xs:element* and *xs:attribute*.
- *imp:image* - adds an icon near the label of a element or attribute.
- *imp:newPage* - the element will display in new page (I had to implement multi page navigation because of the little mobile screen sizes), so a element showed a link and when you press the link the element is displayed in full page. I don't think that this is useful for desktop platforms.
- *imp:view* - some element could have different views (e.g.: you can display a enum or a choice as radio buttons or as a select, you can display a string element as an input or as a textarea, etc.)
- *imp:listLabel*, *imp:listImage*, *imp:newPage* - those are the same as the others but for lists. When something has *maxOccurs>1* or *minOccurs<1* I created a List that could have its own header with its own improvements. Example: a icon of a group of people in the list header and a icon of a person in the header of every occurrence of *person* in the list.

Comment: thanks a lot - this seems like a great answer. I've still got a few questions. 1) Why can't we just use displayname and instead need to refer to a schema xmlns - is it because it would be rejected as a valid xml schema? 2) what's the format like for the "imp" custom schema reference?

Comment: You're welcome. 1) Yes, in order to be valid, custom attributes needs a namespace different to the schema namespace. 2) I am not an English native speaker and think I don'understand this question. Are you asking about how namespaces works?

Comment: Note that it will also be valid if the URI points to a site that does not exists.