# XSD Group enumeration items

Tags: html, xml, xsd

Is it possible to group enumeration values? For example, I want to achieve something like that:

```
<select id="selectId" name="selectName"><option value="">Select Something</option><optgroup label="Group 1"><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option></optgroup></select>
```

My existing XSD code can be found below:

```
    <xsd:simpleType name="myName">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="1" display="A" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="2" display="B" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

Also, my produced html is this:

```
<field name="myName" type="text">
    <option value="" selected="true"/>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</field>
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. It looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600958/xsd-elements-adding-displayname-for-ui-display Also note xs:enumeration does not have a display attribute

Comment: I am asking if somehow I can group the enumeration values.